# The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, uint8list

[The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Uint8List? bytes
Type: Uint8List?]

Reference image - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSbTP.png)

My Code:

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        Uint8List? bytes = await screenshotController.capture();
        imageProvider.changeImage(bytes!);
        if (!mounted) return;
        Navigator.of(context).pop();

        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.done),
)
```

Can someone suggest how to solve this error please? I am a beginner

I tried to pass bytes as parameter with null check, but this isn't working

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXU5o8v4DX0&ab_channel=KODDev**

I was coding after which this yt video. It seems to be working for him (**Time stamp - 52:25**), but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to convert the Uint8List to a File before passing it to the IconButton.

```
Future<void> saveImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String filePath = '${appDocDir.path}/temp_image.png';
  File tempFile = File(filePath);

  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);

  // Now, you can use tempFile as a File
  imageProvider.changeImage(tempFile);

  if (!mounted) return;
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}

// Inside your IconButton's onPressed callback
Uint8List? bytes = await screenshotController.capture();
await saveImage(bytes!);
```

Kellil Amine

Comment: Hi Kellil
I tried your solution. Even though it didnt give any error, when I run the code, the screen kept going blank upon clicking on the 'Tick' icon. What could be the problem??

Comment: Verify that the screenshotController.capture() method is returning the expected Uint8List data. You can add some debugging to print the length or contents of the bytes variable to ensure it contains valid image data.Ensure that the imageProvider.changeImage(tempFile) and Navigator.of(context).pop() lines are working correctly. You can add some print.Without seeing the complete code and the overall structure of your app, it's challenging to pinpoint the exact issue.